# XText Grammar rule for Abstract EMF Class

Tags: xtext, eclipse-emf

I have an EMF metamodel containing Abstract Class `A` and Concrete Classes `B` & `C` implement `A`.

In XText I can have a rule such as `A: B | C;` and refer to A in other rules.

Is there a way not to have to declare the rule for A and have a default rule used for abstract classes (which would be `OR(All concrete children)`) by Just providing the rules for `B` and `C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not possible to call rules you don't have nor a catch all children

if you just want to have child rules and add a parent to them without a explicit rule for the parent

you can do

```
B returns A:
     {B} "b" name=ID;
```

Comment: How do I use A? I have an error "A cannot be resolved to a rule"

Comment: you said you dont want to have or use A rule. so what is your actual problem

Comment: I want not to have to declare the rule for A and have a default rule used for abstract classes (which would be OR(All concrete children)) by Just providing the rules for B and C

Comment: but you want to call rule A?

Comment: I understand it might not be a "rule" but I want to use "A's" such as B by calling "A"

Comment: so you want to do a `someplace=A`, and as said this is not possible without having a `A' rule.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that might be the case